# plot group and category means with group_by

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by

I am new to R and trying to figure out a way to plot means for individual samples as well as group means with ggplot.
I am following this articles on R-bloggers (last paragraph):

https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-individual-observations-and-group-means-with-ggplot2/

This is my code:

```
gd <- meanplot1 %>%
     group_by(treatment, value) %>%
     summarise(measurement = mean(measurement))

ggplot(meanplot1, aes(x=value, y=measurement, color=treatment)) + 
     geom_line(aes(group=sample), alpha=0.3) + 
     geom_line(data=gd, size=3, alpha=0.9) + 
     theme_bw()
```

Whilst the sample means are being shown, the group means aren´t. I get the error
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need
to adjust the group aesthetic?
Upon adding group=1, I get a weirdly mixed category mean, but not what I am looking for..

I scrolled through a lot of articles already, but couldnt find an answer - I would be so happy if somebody could help me out here!! :)

My data (meanplot1) is formatted like this:

```
treatment  sample value measurement
1     control, control 1,     initial,             20,
2     control, control 1,          26,             NA,
3     control, control 1,         26',             28,
12    control, control 2,     initial,             22,
13    control control 2,          26,             NA,
14    control control 2,        26',             36,
15    control control 2,          28,             45,
67   stressed,  stress 1,     initial,             37,
68   stressed,  stress 1,          26,             NA,
69   stressed,  stress 1,         26',             17,
78   stressed,  stress 2,     initial,             36,
79   stressed,  stress 2,          26,             NA,
80   stressed,  stress 2,         26',             25,
```

I am hoping to see 6 lines, one mean for stress 1, stress 2, control 1 and control 2, and one mean for all treatment=control, and one for all treatment=stressed

output dput(gd):

```
structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("control", "stressed"), class = "factor"), value =                 structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("26", "26'", "28", "28'", 
"30", "30'", "32", "32'", "34", "34'", "initial"), class = "factor"), 
measurement = c(NA, 32.3333333333333, 39.5, 30.3333333333333, 
31.8333333333333, 31.8333333333333, NA, 36, 34.6666666666667, 
36, 24.6666666666667, NA, 25.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
32, 50.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, NA, 33.5, 24.3333333333333, 
27.3333333333333, 36)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), vars = list(treatment),       drop = TRUE, .Names = c("treatment", 
"value", "measurement"))
```

output dput(meanplot1):

```
structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label =    c("control", 
"stressed"), class = "factor"), sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("control 1", 
"control 2", "control 3", "control 4", "control 5", "control 6", 
"stress 1", "stress 2", "stress 3", "stress 4", "stress 5", "stress 6"
), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(11L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("26", "26'", 
"28", "28'", "30", "30'", "32", "32'", "34", "34'", "initial"
), class = "factor"), measurement = c(20L, NA, 28L, 18L, 17L, 
19L, 34L, NA, 23L, 29L, 27L, 22L, NA, 36L, 45L, 31L, 40L, 44L, 
NA, 49L, 40L, 39L, 32L, NA, 35L, 57L, 30L, 37L, 29L, NA, 44L, 
37L, 46L, 20L, NA, 39L, 27L, 30L, 40L, 25L, NA, 29L, 50L, 30L, 
26L, NA, 28L, 45L, 47L, 27L, 35L, NA, 24L, 22L, 35L, 28L, NA, 
28L, 45L, 27L, 28L, 24L, NA, 47L, 30L, 39L, 37L, NA, 17L, 29L, 
29L, 31L, 29L, NA, 37L, 21L, 27L, 36L, NA, 25L, 41L, 51L, 66L, 
50L, NA, 33L, 25L, 22L, 36L, NA, 33L, 45L, 26L, 72L, 59L, NA, 
33L, 26L, 25L, 33L, NA, 21L, 33L, 25L, 29L, 21L, NA, 26L, 20L, 
16L, 22L, NA, 30L, 27L, 28L, 57L, 41L, NA, 28L, 23L, 17L, 52L, 
NA, 26L, 25L, 33L, 46L, 35L, NA, 44L, 31L, 57L)), .Names =    c("treatment", 
"sample", "value", "measurement"), class = "data.frame",     row.names = c(NA, 
-132L))
```

Comment: Please provide [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for your question. The expected output would also help greatly.

Comment: Thanks @AdamQuek, I hope this is what you meant? :)

Comment: What does your value `initial` and `26'` mean?

Comment: Moreover, `26` sometimes has a apostrophe like `26'`. Is this intended?

Comment: These are temperature values, they stand for 26°C on the first sampling day, and 26°C on the second sampling day. Initial is the behaviour on the very first experimental day

Comment: So if your `values` for `meanplot1` is categorical, how did you manage to run `gd <- meanplot1 %>% group_by(treatment, value) %>% summarise(value = mean(value))` in the first place?

Comment: sorry sorry sorry, I changed the names of my variables to have clearer names in this post and messed up - it is summarise(measurement = mean(measurement))

Comment: Your sample data are a mess. Please [edit] your Q and add the result of `dput(gd)` - Thank you

Comment: Hi Uwe, thanks for your reply. I unfortunately dont understand what you mean by "Q" but added the result of dput(gd)

Comment: @Axeman the data in the beginning is an excerpt from meanplot1, I added the output from dput(meanplot1) now, thanks for taking the time to look at this question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are aiming to plot the treatment means.

By default, since you are using a categorical x-axis, the grouping is set to the interaction between x and color. You only want to group by treatment, however. So we'll add the correct grouping to the call.

```
ggplot(meanplot1, aes(x = value, y = measurement, color=treatment)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=sample), alpha=0.3) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = treatment), gd, size=3, alpha=0.9) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Also note that

```
ggplot(meanplot1, aes(x=value, y=measurement, color=treatment)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=sample), alpha=0.3) + 
  stat_summary(aes(group = treatment), fun.y = mean, geom = 'line', size=3, alpha=0.9) +
  theme_bw()
```

Gives the same plot, without the interruption.

Comment: wow great, thank you so much that works for me! :) I really appreciate it! Now I am only left with the problem of "initial" jumping to the end of the x axis for some reason..

Comment: Check the order of your factor levels. See [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402242/keep-same-order-as-in-data-files-when-using-ggplot).

Comment: amazing, thank you, meanplot2<-transform(meanplot1, value=factor(value, levels=unique(tvalue))) worked for me. Also thanks for the second edit of the plot, I was working on a solution for the interpolation of missing data when I saw yours! I suppose I cannot use fun.y for the interpolation of the other lines, since it is solely a function in the stat_summary operator?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using `stat_summary(aes(group = sample), fun.y = mean, geom = 'line', alpha = 0.3)` though.