# ggplot2 continuous color scale AND same datetime order as in data set

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, time-series

I want to combine two features of these plots - gradient colors and colorbar guide in a legend as seen in (1) and plot with same datetime order as in file as in (2).

(1) Does not display the data correctly - I want to connect points within one date and not 07:00:00 in date == 5 being followed by 07:00:00 in date == 10.

```
d = ggplot(data.test, aes(x = fakeTime, y = Wh, col = Date)) + geom_line() +
scale_colour_gradient2()
```

[image: ggplot2 plot which displays data wrong]

(2) This problem is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402242/keep-same-order-as-in-data-files-when-using-ggplot) by using Date as factor, which doesn't allow continuous color scale.

```
data.test <- transform(data.test,Date=factor(Date,levels=unique(Date)))
d = ggplot(data.test, aes(x = fakeTime, y = Wh, col = Date)) + geom_line() +
 scale_colour_hue(l = 20, c = 60)
```

[image: ggplot2 plot without continuous colorbar]

fakeTime was created because of another stack exchange answer, which solved plotting same time of different dates simultaneously (like in (2)) by introducing a new date, which was the same across all values. Ultimately, the correct date was extracted from datetime and is found in Date column, e.g. 5 stands for actual date of 2019-03-05.

Here is my example data set, that can be read by

```
read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

```
"Date","time","Wh","fakeTime"
5,"07:00:00",0.45,2019-03-01 07:00:00
5,"08:00:00",6.14,2019-03-01 08:00:00
5,"09:00:00",6.89,2019-03-01 09:00:00
5,"10:00:00",13.26,2019-03-01 10:00:00
5,"11:00:00",12.66,2019-03-01 11:00:00
5,"12:00:00",27.05,2019-03-01 12:00:00
5,"13:00:00",14.41,2019-03-01 13:00:00
5,"14:00:00",5.75,2019-03-01 14:00:00
5,"15:00:00",2.78,2019-03-01 15:00:00
5,"16:00:00",1.37,2019-03-01 16:00:00
5,"17:00:00",0,2019-03-01 17:00:00
10,"07:00:00",0.32,2019-03-01 07:00:00
10,"08:00:00",6.12,2019-03-01 08:00:00
10,"09:00:00",22.88,2019-03-01 09:00:00
10,"10:00:00",10.32,2019-03-01 10:00:00
10,"11:00:00",18.33,2019-03-01 11:00:00
10,"12:00:00",23.17,2019-03-01 12:00:00
10,"13:00:00",22.21,2019-03-01 13:00:00
10,"14:00:00",27.09,2019-03-01 14:00:00
10,"15:00:00",12.78,2019-03-01 15:00:00
10,"16:00:00",4.22,2019-03-01 16:00:00
10,"17:00:00",0.94,2019-03-01 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting group = Date inside the aes() in the ggplot() and geom_line(aes(col = Date))

```
ggplot(data.test, aes(x = fakeTime, y = Wh, group = Date)) + geom_line(aes(col = 
Date)) +
scale_colour_gradient2()
```

[image]

Comment: We need to use as.numeric(Date) as you firstly propose, I think.